# What's the difference between libm.lib, libmmt.lib, and libmmds.lib?

Tags: c++, windows, linker, libm

[Intel describes](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/libraries-provided-by-intelr-c-compiler-for-windows-and-intel-parallel-composer) libm.lib as a static library, libmmt.lib as a multi-threaded static library (/MT) and libmmds.lib as a multi-threaded static library (/MD) all implementing the [LibM Math Library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implement-the-libm-math-library).

But don't you always have to choose either /MT or /MD? Why are there 3 static versions of the library on Windows, rather than just two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for old VC6 that has a a runtime for single threaded application!! but for now you are correct, we don't have it any more!

Comment: Thanks. I definitely don't want to link to that, then.